# Why is my RecordCount always -1?

Tags: asp-classic

I want to run a SQL query to just see if data of an ID is already in the database.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317424/how-to-test-for-an-empty-sql-result-in-asp) to achieve that.

But it doesn't work. The database does have rows and when I run the exact SQL queries, it shows me several results. But `RecordCount` seems to be always `-1`. Even this isn't recognized in the following `IF` clause. Here's my code:

```
sqlCommand2 =   "SELECT * FROM database " &_
                "WHERE row = 'whatever';"
                SET objRS2 = objConn.Execute(sqlCommand2)

                Wscript.Echo "RecordCount: " & objRS2.RecordCount 'ALWAYS returns -1

                IF objRS2.RecordCount > 0 THEN
```

**Why is RecordCount always set to -1?**

Comment: My solution now is to do a `DO WHILE NOT objRS2.EOF Counter-up` clause, which works. But I just want to understand why my RecordCount always has been -1.

Comment: This happens if you're using a forward only cursor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676676(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the cursor type to adOpenStatic. You can use the function below.

*Note that you will need to include your connection string below.

```
  Function RS(strSQL)
     Dim oConn, oRs 
     Set oConn  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
     oConn.CommandTimeout = 1800
     oConn.Open("[ConnectionStringValueGoesHere]")

     Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
     oRs.CursorLocation = 3 
     oRS.Open strSQL, oConn, 3, 4
     oRS.ActiveConnection = Nothing
     oConn.Close
     Set oConn = Nothing

     Set executeSQLreturnRS = oRs
 End Function
```

So change this line:

```
SET objRS2 = objConn.Execute(sqlCommand2)
```

To:

```
SET objRS2 = RS(sqlCommand2)
```

Comment: @trollwut The lines `oRs.CursorLocation = 3` and `oRS.Open strSQL, oConn, 3, 4` change the cursor type which is what John is suggesting and is the reason it doesn't work, there is no need to switch to using disconnected recordsets.

Comment: May you improve your answer to that, Luke Ford? (Or should I say... Harrison Skywalker? AAAAAAAhhh... I need weekend.)

Comment: @Trollwut LOL, Harrison Skywalker is a new one. I've updated the answer to reflect the cursor type change. Thank you.